# Find an error in computation of $H^n(RP^\infty;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ using cellular structure of the real projective space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fake-proofs

I'm following Milnor and Stasheff, Characteristic classes, now it leaves without proof the computation of $H^*(RP^\infty;Z_2)$. I know about the computation in Hatcher's book, nevertheless I thought I could use the CW complex structure that is computed in the book and a couple of theorems to avoid doing such long proof, I tried but I found a contradiction and I cannot locate the error. So if anyone would be so kind to point out were I'm mistaken or how to fix the proof I would appreciate it.
Here are the facts I have already seen:

1. I know that $RP^\infty$ has exactly one cell for each dimension as a CW complex, check corollary 6.5.
2. Since we are working in a field $\mathbb{Z}_2$ then $H^i(X)=Hom(X,\mathbb{Z}_2)$. Check theorem A.1 and apply the fact that the ring is a field.
3. If $K$ is a CW complex and $R$ a commutative ring with unity then the relative homology group $H_i(K^n,K^{n-1})$ with coefficients in $R$ is 0 if $i\neq n$ and is a free $R$-module if $i=n$ with a generator for each $n$-cell of $K^n$, check lemma A.2, in particular if it consists of a single cell one gets it is isomorphic to $R$.
4. If $K$ is a CW complex then $H^i(K^n)$ is zero for $i>n$ and isomorphic to $H_i(K)$ for i<n. The same statement follows for cohomology. Check corollary A.3

Since there is only one generator for each cell in $K^n$ then $H_n(K^n,K^{n-1})$, by applying 3 we get that, it is a free module over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ with rank one which means it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Applying 2. we have that $H^n(K^n,K^{n-1})=Hom(\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Let $K=RP^\infty$ now we compute H^n(K^n) by induction, for $n=0$ by applying 2. $H^0(K^0)=End(\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2=\mathbb{Z}_2[a]/[a]$. Now with the short exact sequence of cochains given by the quocient we derive the long exact sequence:
$$
...\longleftarrow H^n(K^{n-1})\longleftarrow H^{n}(K^n)\longleftarrow H^{n}(K^n,K^{n-1})\longleftarrow H^{n-1}(K^{n-1})\longleftarrow H^{n-1}(K^n)\longleftarrow H^{n-1}(K^n,K^{n-1})\longleftarrow...
$$
now we already know that $H^n(K^n,K^{n-1})=\mathbb{Z}_2$, by 2 we also get $H^{n-1}(K^n,K^{n-1})=0$ and by 4 we have that $H^{n}(K^{n-1})=0$ and that $H^{n-1}(K^n)=H^{n-1}(K^{n-1})=\mathbb{Z}_2[a]/[a^n]$ by induction. Thus we are left with the sequence:
$$
...\longleftarrow 0\longleftarrow H^{n}(K^n)\longleftarrow \mathbb{Z}_2\longleftarrow \mathbb{Z}_2[a]/[a^n]\longleftarrow \mathbb{Z}_2[a]/[a^n]\longleftarrow 0\longleftarrow...
$$
Now by exactness, the map between $\mathbb{Z}_2[a]/[a^n]$ and the $\mathbb{Z}_2[a]/[a^n]$ is an isomorphism since it is injective because of the 0 and therefore bijective since they are finite modules of the same dimension and it is a homomorphism. Thus the map from $\mathbb{Z}_2[a]/[a^n]$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ must be 0, which concludes that $\mathbb{Z}_2\cong H^{n}(K^n)$ but we know this is false, so where is the error?

Comment: Wait, isn't $H^n(\mathbb{RP}^\infty;\mathbb Z_2)\cong \mathbb Z_2$? What is the contradiction you are seeing?

Comment: The final conclusion is correct but the statement $H^{n-1}(K^n)=H^{n-1}(K^{n-1})=\mathbb{Z}_2[a]/[a^n]$ is wrong.  The induction hypothesis tells you that $H^{n-1}(K^{n-1})\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$ (not $\mathbb{Z}_2[a]/[a^n]$ which is instead the value of the entire cohomology ring $H^*(K^{n-1})$).  It does not tell you what $H^{n-1}(K^n)$ is.  Indeed, you *cannot* determine what $H^{n-1}(K^n)$ is (and therefore what $H^n(K^n)$ is) using only the information you are considering--merely knowing that $K$ has one cell in each dimension does not uniquely determine its cohomology.

Comment: I see now I got confused with the graded ring, thank you very much. Just for the sake of curiosity, do you know any other CW complex that only has one cell in each dimension and has different cohomology?